# How to add an id from MySQL to a session cookie

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I followed a tutorial to Create a Secure Login Script in PHP and MySQL
there we made a function that made a secure session and created a cookie with it.

```
<?php
    function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'COOKIENAME';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = SECURE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
?>
```

now i want to add to that cookie  the user id that i have in a mysql database
i want to use those id's  for later so i can get more data from the user if i need.
or store settings they have selected.

how would i do that?
should i add something into the login function that on login the ID gets added to the session cookie?

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
// Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt 
    FROM members
   WHERE email = ?
    LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
    $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();

    // get variables from result.
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
    $stmt->fetch();

    // hash the pasword with the unique salt.
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
        // from too many login attempts 

        if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Account is locked 
            // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
            return false;
        } else {
            // Chec k if the password in the database matches
            // the password the user submitted.
            if ($db_password == $password) {
                // Password is correct!
                // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                            "", 
                                                            $username);
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                          $password . $user_browser);
                // Login successful.
                return true;
            } else {
                // Password is not correct
                // We record this attempt in the database
                $now = time();
                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // No user exists.
        return false;
    }
}
```

link to tutorial http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: You have the right idea.  read http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php    Note that you can't ever "update" a cookie, you can only overwrite it using the `setcookie()` function

Comment: isn't it allready done in `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;` ? Do `var_dump($_SESSION);` you will see that your user id is allready stored in :p

Comment: i get "'login_string' => string '9bf140a86b620cba0c2fabcc7866ad71c84c99b68d2fdb and some more"

but its not the id number in the database

Comment: if i do echo $_COOKIE["COOKIENAME"]; i get a sting that changes all the time, like this: 11tnlfartliggm5glaehkff0eu2

Comment: i got it i needed to use 
    <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user_id']); ?>
i so happy it only took me a few hours to find how to do that.
Thanks!

Comment: i have a other question i can not show the users email with <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['email']); ?> 
how would i make a new function that would let met output the email from that cookie? so that i can use that piece of code i would like to use that for all the output i want to show like email or the date of the created account. i guess for the last one i would need to also add something to the register page that will save the date into the database

Comment: $_SESSION['email'] hasn't been set yet. Add $_SESSION["email'] = $email; next to $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

Answer (score 0):

You add session like this  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
A session is just an array that doesn't go away and you access it via $_SESSION[]